# Undo changes to the main branch

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, git-filter-branch

I made changes to the main branch like pushing the changes to another branch and just resetting the main branch to default

try:git reset --hard origin/main
but it resets all the ramifications, does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: (a) we don't know what you mean when you say, "it resets all the ramifications", and (b) `git reset --hard origin/main` seems like the right thing if you goal is to reset the state to that of the remote repository. If you're trying to do something else, show us the specific set of actions that brought you to your current state and explain clearly what exactly you want to undo.

Comment: @Raf4Killer explain a bit more! what actually happened?

Comment: I made changes to the main branch, I want to rename it and download the main branch from the repository again.
staying:
*main (no changes)
*renamed branch (with changes)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same problem as mine, this was the step by step guide to solve it:

1 - **git branch -m new-branch-name** (rename the branch where the change was made)

2 - **git checkout main** (go back to the main branch)

Then you will have the default main branch and the changed branch.